# D&D 5e Feats - Blade Mastery

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

[image]

Hello.
last week,(week of june 12 2016) the Feat - Blade Mastery was removed from the wikia section on feats. but a week before that it was there. my question is, is it removed? and cant be used in an AL sanctioned adventure?

CAN I STILL USE BLADE MASTERY AS A FEAT IN AN AL SANCTIONED CAMPAIGN?

Comment: "Is it removed" from what? The game? The wiki? Adventure League? Have you checked your D&D 5e books yet to see if it's in there?

Comment: I will note, for visitors to this question, that this appears to be about a Wikia site which openly reproduces/pirates non-OGL D&D 5e content.

Comment: oh. so the Wikia site i saw is FAKE?  its not in the PHB actually. its so confusing which to rely. sorry i just started 2 weeks ago

Comment: As far as I can deduce it is an unofficial site which aims to reproduce the real content from the books. Since that's illegal, our community generally avoids condoning sites that do this, including by simply not linking to them as reference material. We haven't yet been asked a direct question about one of these sites before, though, so this question isn't covered by any policy of ours I'm aware of.

Comment: D&D 5e *has* released an OGL copy of the game ([official source here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), [compiled legally on a website here](http://5thsrd.org/)) but it's *very* skint on actual content. The feats section suffers the most - there's only one feat even listed. I have *no* idea why they chose to do it that way, tbh.

Comment: @doppelgreener From my understanding, the limited content under the OGL from the 5e SRD is because it is meant to be used as "sampler" material for 3rd party publishers.  For example, it includes the base classes and one archetype from each class to give 3rd parties the base class details and an example archetype from which to build their own class archetypes.  I assume that the inclusion of a single feat was to illustrate how different feats are from 3.5e, and to give an example feat (since the *rules* for feats are under the OGL) without giving away all of that content.

Answer (score 7):

That feat and burglar below it are from the June 2016 unearthed arcana. Everything in UA is beta and not usable in AL events.